# Regex in Oracle - How can I check if a word does not occur?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I am currently using regex in Oracle to search a text for certain words. For example, if I want to search for the number of times "good performance" occurs, I want to exclude all sequences in which "not" appears. So I want to filter "good performance" and exclude "not good performance". On regex build pages it would work like this:

(?!not)+(good performance).

But unfortunately in my script it doesn't work. What would be the corresponding expression in Oracle?
Currently I used:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('not good performance',
        '(?!not)+(\sgood performance)',1,1,'i',2) 
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: `(?!not)+(good performance)` won't work in any environment, you confuse what lookaheads do and how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value 
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_SUBSTR (
         value,
         '(not\s+)?(good performance)',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) IS NULL;
```

or, without regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT value 
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LOWER(value) LIKE '%good performance%'
AND    LOWER(value) NOT LIKE '%not good performance%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT  'Good Performance' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  'No, it is not. Good performance!' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  'NOT GOOD PERFORMANCE' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| Good Performance |
| No, it is not. Good performance! |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JNqF4dkc)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need regular expressions? How about `instr`?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'that is not good performance at all' from dual union all
  3     select 'yes, it is good performance!'        from dual
  4    )
  5  select *
  6  from test
  7  where instr(col, 'good performance') > 0
  8    and instr(col, 'not good performance') = 0;

COL
-----------------------------------
yes, it is good performance!

SQL>
```

Comment: I probably do, I don't know instr now, so I don't know what else it can do. but I simplified the expression especially for the question and I also need the word before "performance" so I need to know if it says "good" or "satisfied" and so on.